DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value
I have a column called date that is currently as data type text.
I try to change it to date and this is what happens:

The error says:
DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value.
Details:
    1/23/2022

I don't understand why.
I've been changing the data type of this column previously in other reports without problem.

Does it have invisible characters? Spaces before or after? Try adding a custom column with formula =Text.Length([columnnamehere]) and see how many characters it thinks it has

Posting an alternative solution for awareness where one can select the Locale of the Data Transformation...

Click on the ABC in the column header and then select Using Locale...


Then select Data Type Date and Locale English (United States)



In Power Query, you can specify the Locale as the third parameter (eg "en-US"):
Table.TransformColumnTypes(PreviousStep, {{"date", type date}}, "en-US")


OH, I will try that tomorrow. Thank you. Better than creating a new column

Power Query interprets dates based on the regional settings defined for your query. For example, the format 1/23/2022 will be recognized as valid in regional settings that use the month/day/year format (such as in the U.S.), but not in settings that use the day/month/year format (common in many European or Latin American countries).
You can adjust the regional settings of the query by doing this:
Click on File > Options and Settings > Options > Current File > Regional Settings.
Change the regional settings to match the date format (e.g., "English (United States)" for MM/DD/YYYY).
Another solution is to create a new column that parses the data.
= Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "ParsedDate", each Date.FromText([date], "en-US"), type date)


Thank you @Augustin, I'm gonna test it today. By the way as you can see the date is 1/23/2023 and I'm using English(Switzerland) in the regional settings so it should be fine. I don't understand why shifting to English USA.

Your solution worked and picked up automatically the date DD/MM/YYYY
